# Apache 2.4 proxy requests to web app not working

Tags: python, apache, proxy, pylons

We migrated our web hosting to a newer server running Apache 2.4.6, Plesk 12.5, and CentOS7.2. The web app is written in the Python Pylons framework. It utilizes `paster` to serve the web application. I have verified `paster` is running on port `28178` on `localhost` and it shows up when I use `top`. I have been using this documentation in setting it up along with comparing it to the old server files where the application is still running fine:

[Using Apache to Proxy Requests to Pylons](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/deployment.html#using-apache-to-proxy-requests-to-pylons)

I have gone into the domain's `vhost_ssl.conf` added servername, serveralias, etc. and made sure it is pointing at the port the app is running on and that the app's production.ini is specified to that port. Everything indicates the `paster` server and Apache should be talking to one another, but when I go to the new server, it is not serving the web app.

I should point out, I haven't changed over DNS so I have to go to the new server using it's IP address. Not sure if this could be interfering with it, but I will check it out.

Any suggestions or further information needed? And I have restart `httpd` since I made the updates to the conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add the new IP and domain to the local HOSTS file to overwrite the DNS pointing the domain at the old server's IP. That way I can test it, change the DNS when done, and restore my host file.